# How to add references from difference filetypes: .bib and .text

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, multiple-files, multiple-citations

I am working on the overleaf exampe of the "universe". I wanted to try to add a reference to the current (uses bib) list of references. But instead I want to use a tex file.

Is there a way to add the tex file together with the bib file?

I have this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\title{Universe}
\author{Overleaf}
\date{September 2020}

\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
There is a theory which states that if ever anyone discovers exactly what the Universe is for and why it is here, it will instantly disappear and be replaced by something even more bizarre and inexplicable.
There is another theory which states that this has already happened.

\section{Conclusion}
``I always thought something was fundamentally wrong with the universe'' \citep{adams1995hitchhiker}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{references}
\end{document}
```

The `reference.bib` looks like this:

```
@book{adams1995hitchhiker,
  title={The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy},
  author={Adams, D.},
  isbn={9781417642595},
  url={http://books.google.com/books?id=W-xMPgAACAAJ},
  year={1995},
  publisher={San Val}
}
```

The `ref.tex` looks like this:

```
@article{PhysRev.47.777,
  title = {Can Quantum-Mechanical Description of Physical Reality Be Considered Complete?},
  author = {Einstein, A. and Podolsky, B. and Rosen, N.},
  journal = {Phys. Rev.},
  volume = {47},
  issue = {10},
  pages = {777--780},
  numpages = {0},
  year = {1935},
  month = {May},
  publisher = {American Physical Society},
  doi = {10.1103/PhysRev.47.777},
  url = {https://link.aps.org/doi/10.1103/PhysRev.47.777}
}
```

When I try to add the `ref.tex` to `bibliography` I don't get any output.

I did this in the main tex file, for `bibliography`:

```
\bibliography{references,ref}
```

But didn't work. Is there any package that I should import first so that it works like above to reference a tex file after bib file?

The current output is:

[image]

I would like the ref.tex to follow this one too in [2].

Comment: Just rename `ref.tex` to `ref.bib`.  Note also that the format of the file `ref` is not in the form of latex macros...it is in the form of the BibTeX language...that is why it should not be named `ref.tex`.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes, you are right. It works. It's first time on latex and I didn't know I have to cite it first for it to appear. Thanks.

Comment: Using BibTeX to get citations to appear in a document is a multi-step compilation process, yes.  Would you like this question to be closed, or are you still looking for a formal "answer"?

Comment: I would like it closed. I am happy with your input. @StevenB.Segletes

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because a comment clarified for the OP what he needed to do differently.